# Python requests return 403 even after setting user agent header and using session

Tags: python, session, python-requests, user-agent, request-headers

I am trying to scrape this website: https://batdongsan.com.vn/ban-can-ho-chung-cu-king-palace. But requests fails to get the website.

I have added user agent and used session in my code. This is what I did:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0    (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) \
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

"""step 2 get url"""
URL = "https://batdongsan.com.vn/ban-can-ho-chung-cu-king-palace"
session = requests.Session()
page = session.get(URL, headers=headers)
print(page.status_code)
```

The result is as follow:

```
403
```

I have tried the same exact code with another website, https://homedy.com. I only replaced the URL and kept everything else the exact same.
And running the code gives me:

```
200
```

So my understanding is that there is something to the first website that prevented my code from working. But I can't figure out how to get past it.
I would appreciate it very much if anyone has any solution to the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your webiste uses some advanced request-fingerprinting.

You could try using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75275395/20443541) tho.